# Add a new less file in bootstrap package extension on typo3

Tags: less, typo3

I need to add a new style in typo3 but with less file, because I am using the bootstrap package theme in typo3 (v7.4.0) and this template use the less files and later compress all in one file with @import method and convert in .css file.

So the problem is: I upload some new file in less using filelist: bootstrap-package/Resources/Public/Less/Theme and later use the @import method in theme.less file but after of that, my new style not appear.

I cleaned the cache, I changed many constants configuration for see some change but nothing yet.

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

i tried to add a new less file, named my.less
then used a variable to change h1 heading.
I inserted the variable within the variables.less file located in the folder

```
../Theme/
```

then changed the access to allow the access from apache:

```
`chmod 0775 my.less`
`chown apache:apache my.less`
```

and inserted it adding a line within theme.less as follows:

```
@import "typo3_form.less";
@import "my.less";
```

saved / cleared the cache and it works.

Comment: Hi Gilas, thanks for your answer. I'll try this option, because I haven't access to the server directly but I shared this solution with my boss for trying him and after I'll share with you the result.

Comment: For other hand - I found something stranger in filelist, because If delete some file in bootstrap-package/.../Less/ or /Css/ the style should be broken but I tried this but nothing happens (I cleaned the cache after that...). It is as if all files that is hosted there, not has use.

If I try to do some change about the less files in typo3conf\ext\bootstrap_package\Resources...\Less\  works well but my boss says it is a bad solution changing the code in "ext" folders and should in "fileadmin" or filelist.

Comment: The problem was fixed. If you have the template files on filelist, should including this on the template setup record:

<pre>
  <code>
    includeCSS {
        theme = fileadmin/bootstrap-package/Resources/Public/Less/Theme/theme.less
    }

</code>
</pre>

The theme.less should have the @import 'custom.less".

Comment: Hi Victor... just thought I'd point out that it's not recommended to place these theme specific things in fileadmin since items there are supposed to be tracked by TYPO3 filelist module. It's better to create a blank extension and put the file in `my_extension/Resources/Public/Less/Theme/custom.less`. If you don't know how to create a dummy extension you could look at the builder extension in TER, GitHub, or composer... http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?id=23&L=0&q=builder, https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/builder, or https://composer.typo3.org/satis.html#!/builder